# Fixing “expected token 'name', got 'integer'” error in python flask with Jinja 2 templating

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, web-deployment

I really face an error in Flask.
When I try to put if statement to insert some elements inside it, a token error saying `expected token 'name', got 'integer'` arise.

And when I try to delete if statement then the token error disappears and the entire page with its contents is smoothly displayed.

Below are some of my codes.

**Page.html**

```
{% for content in contents %}
   <div>
       *some divs here*
       {{content}}
   </div>

{% if content.index is 3 %}
   <div>
        *some contents inside*
   </div>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `if` statement condition, you should use `==` rather than `is`.

`is` is used to compare against the type rather than the value.